# keydown event.target is not correct

Tags: javascript

In the below snippet my goal is to log the element where user is typing. But when the user is typing in `span`, the event target is still `div`.

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
 console.log("event.target.nodeName -> ", event.target.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<i>Type in "world" below</i>
<div contenteditable="true" id=wrapper>
  hello 
  <span> world!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*But when the user is typing in span, the event target is still div.*"

No dasfdsa. The user is not typing in `span`. The user is typing in the `div`.

This is the `span`

[image: The span is just this much].

And here is the `div`

[image: The entire part is the div]

Also note the `contenteditable="true"` in your code, it is set to the div, not the `span`. That is why the `event.target.nodeName` shows `div` and not `span`.

Setting the `contenteditable="true"` to the `span` should get your job done, something like below

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
 console.log("event.target.nodeName -> ", event.target.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<i>Type in "world" below</i>
<div id=wrapper>
  hello 
  <span contenteditable="true" > world!</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** It seems that the typing does happen in the `span`, thanks to Kaiido for this info. But the `event.target` returns the parent element(which I don't actually know why).

Comment: The user is typing in the span too. Simply set the css to `span { color: red }`, set your cursor in that span an type. What you type will be red and part of this span, i.e you just typed inside the span.

Comment: That's something new to me @Kaiido. Thanks for the info.. Will edit my answer, based on this, but why does it return `div` as the target even if it actually is the `span`? I didn't quite understand this even from your answer(apologies if my question seems too stupid or redundant though).

Comment: My answer doesn't give a clear why either, I admit. I didn't had time yet to fully read the specs and thus couldn't find the clear "why" I could link to in my own answer. But the gist is that the *focus-area* is actually the *editable-host*, and that key inputs should always be dispatched to the *focus-area*, not its children. But `content-editable` is quite a poor children in the specs and a lot is left to the implementers to guess...

Comment: Thanks.. Didn't get it completely.. But great for a start and a basic idea! Lots there to learn I guess..

Answer (score 2):

One way to get this Element is to check what's the current Range's [`commonAncestorContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) is.
This will return the Node where your cursor is currently in (and thus where you are typing). To get the closest element, you can simply check the nodeType of this node and return its `parentElement` if it wasn't an Element.

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener('input', (event)=>{
  console.log("currently typing in ->", getFocusedElement() ); 
});

function getFocusedElement() {
  const node = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
  return node.nodeType === 1 ? node : node.parentElement;  
}
```

```html
<i>Type in "world" below</i>
<div contenteditable="true" id=wrapper>
  hello 
  <span> world!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The span is within the div and events will propagate from child - the span, to the handler on the div. To access the element of the handler use `event.currentTarget` Vs `event.target` which is the element that triggered the event.

Comment: e.target references the event target, 
e.currentTarget is the node which the listener was registered on

Comment: Dasfda, it’s not wrong. Your understanding of how events propagate is incorrect. JS/dom 101

Comment: @Chev but the question is actually why are they always getting currentTarget === target